# When I download a json file using curl, json_decode returns an empty array

Tags: php, json

When I download a json file using curl, json_decode returns an empty array. But when I use the same file from the webpage without downloading, then everything works.
I need to download this file, because it weighs 150 MB

curl code:

```
<?php
url = 'https://localhost.8888/apartments.json';
$destFile = 'aparts.json';

$fp = fopen($destFile, 'w+b');
if (false === $fp) {
    throw new RuntimeException ( 'fopen() failed.   last error: ' . return_var_dump ( error_get_last () ) );
}
$ch = curl_init();
if (false === $ch) {
    throw new RuntimeException ( 'curl_init() failed.   last error: ' . return_var_dump ( error_get_last () ) );
}

ecurl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
ecurl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); // write curl response to file
ecurl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
ecurl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
ecurl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
ecurl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp);
ecurl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);



function ecurl_setopt ( /*resource*/$ch , int $option , /*mixed*/ $value ):bool{
    $ret=curl_setopt($ch,$option,$value);
    if($ret!==true){
        //option should be obvious by stack trace
        throw new RuntimeException ( 'curl_setopt() failed. curl_errno: ' . return_var_dump ( curl_errno ($ch) ).'. curl_error: '.curl_error($ch) );
    }
    return true;
}
function ecurl_exec ( /*resource*/$ch)/*:mixed depending on CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER*/{
    $ret=curl_exec($ch);
    if($ret===false){
        throw new RuntimeException ( 'curl_exec() failed. curl_errno: ' . return_var_dump ( curl_errno ($ch) ).'. curl_error: '.curl_error($ch) );
    }
    return $ret;
}


function return_var_dump(){
    $args = func_get_args ();
    ob_start ();
    call_user_func_array ( 'var_dump', $args );
    return ob_get_clean ();
}
?>
```

and json_decode code

```
<?php
$json_apartments = file_get_contents('aparts.json');
$data_apartments = (array)json_decode($json_apartments,true);

foreach($data_apartments as $jsons_apartments) 
{
$_id = $json_apartments['_id'];
$area_balconies_total = $json_apartments['area_balconies_total'];
$area_given = $json_apartments['area_given'];
}
?>
```

JSON file looks like

```
[
{
    "_id": "1cv",
    "area_balconies_total": 0,
    "area_given": 57.2
}
]
```

Before that, I encountered the Invalid argument supplied for foreach() error.
I changed

```
$data_apartments = json_decode($json_apartments,true);
```

to

```
$data_apartments = (array)json_decode($json_apartments,true);
```

At first I thought that was the problem, but it turned out that it wasn't

Аfter that I added

case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
echo ' - Syntax error';
break;

And I got the error:Array - Syntax error, malformed JSON

Comment: The example given is not valid JSON. It has an extra comma at the end of the 3rd value.

Comment: When I use CRON the server throws an out of memory error

Comment: I removed the comma, accidentally put it when I was writing an example of a json file

Comment: Does it work with a smaller file?

Comment: No, with smaller file not working

Comment: Then why don't you post an example of a small file that doesn't work?

Comment: There are 5kk lines in this file, in a smaller one, which I tried about 1000 lines

Comment: Find the smallest file that doesn't work. That's called debugging...

Comment: I fix it. Oliver, thank u. It is my error

Comment: Unfortunately, PHP's JSON error handling is not very specific about where the problem is. Try pasting the file contents into jsonlint.com.